# How to invalidate localStorage after breaking change

Tags: javascript

I have this little piece of code which is allowing me to check if user has localStorage set before I've made breaking changes in it's format.

```
var sw =
{
  storage: {
    // change this date when you create breaking changes in local storage
    // any local storage set before this time will be invalidated & set again
    lastBreakingUpdateTime: new Date(2017, 4, 24),

    local: {
      set: function(key, value) {
        try {
          window.localStorage.setItem(key.toString(), value.toString());
          return true;
        }
        catch(e) {
          return false;
        }
      },

      get: function(key) {
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem(key.toString());

        if (value === 'true')
          return true;
        if (value === 'false')
          return false;

        // isNan returns false for empty string
        // empty string is considered 0 by isNaN, but NaN by parseInt :)
        if (isNaN(value) || value === '')
          return value;

        // return value converted to number
        return +value;
      },

      markAsSetNow: function() {
        sw.storage.local.set('timeWhenSet', new Date());
      },

      isOutdatedOrNotSet: function() {
        var lastSetTime = sw.storage.local.get('timeWhenSet');
        if (!lastSetTime ||  Date.parse(lastSetTime) <= sw.storage.lastBreakingUpdateTime)
          return true;

        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Issue with this code is that in javascript Date.Parse is unreliable accross browsers - each browser has different implementation. I need to modify this code so that it works reliably in every major browser.

Comment: try setting a version number, always check if the browser version is the same as the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Use time in ms to compare the dates in order to check the cache:

```
const ms = new Date().getTime();
```

It is [cross-browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about this. I'd except it, but I need to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I have decided to use a format version number, like ayinloya has suggested in comments. Here is my complete local storage handling code, if someone wants to use in their apps.

```
var appName =
{
  storage: {
    // increment this when you create breaking changes in local storage format
    // versions must start from 1, version 0 is invalid
    formatVersion: 1,

    // type can be 'localStorage' or 'sessionStorage'
    available: function(type) {
      try {
        var storage = window[type],
            x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
      }
      catch(e) {
        return false;
      }
    },

    local: {
      // Use this function over window.localStorage.setItem() because
      // localStorage.setItem() or sessionStorage.setItem() may throw
      // an exception if the storage is full.
      // in Mobile Safari (since iOS 5) it always throws when the user
      // enters private mode (Safari sets quota to 0 bytes in private mode,
      // contrary to other browsers, which allow storage in private mode,
      // using separate data containers).
      set: function(key, value) {
        try {
          window.localStorage.setItem(key.toString(), value.toString());
          return true;
        }
        catch(e) {
          return false;
        }
      },

      get: function(key) {
        var value = window.localStorage.getItem(key.toString());

        if (value === 'true')
          return true;
        if (value === 'false')
          return false;

        // isNan returns false for empty string
        // empty string is considered 0 by isNaN, but NaN by parseInt :)
        if (isNaN(value) || value === '')
          return value;

        // return value converted to number
        return +value;
      },

      setFormatVersion: function() {
        appName.storage.local.set('formatVersion', appName.storage.formatVersion);
      },

      isOutdatedOrNotSet: function() {
        var version = appName.storage.local.get('formatVersion');
        if (!version || version < appName.storage.formatVersion)
          return true;

        return false;
      }
    }
  }
}
```